# where can i place SELECT @rank:=0 in this query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I need to place `set @rank:=0;` in this query, but where can i place it?

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, p.* FROM points p 
inner join distributor d 
on p.distributor_id=d.id_distributor 
where p.month='$prev_month' 
and d.group='$dist_group' 
ORDER BY p.tot_point DESC
```

i have to use `mysql_query("set @rank:=0;");` before the main query, it's works. but in another server it won't work.

any ideas ?

Comment: mysql version in another server ?

Comment: Put it as another `INNER JOIN` with nested select: `INNER JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) x`

Comment: +1 @gowri And Gunslinger_ What do you mean by mysql in another server?

Comment: i don't know why, but it's doesn't work when i migrate it to server from localhost.

Comment: @zerkms - But what is the `JOIN` condition would be in this case?

Comment: server mysql server is : 3.5.3

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, p.* FROM points p, (SELECT @rank:=0) AS dummy
inner join distributor d 
on p.distributor_id=d.id_distributor 
where p.month='$prev_month' 
and d.group='$dist_group' 
ORDER BY p.tot_point DESC
```

Basicly just add `, (SELECT @rank:=0) AS dummy` after `FROM points p`.

My prefered layout on this query:

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, p.*
FROM 
    points AS p
  CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT @rank:=0) AS dummy
  INNER JOIN 
    distributor AS d
      ON p.distributor_id = d.id_distributor 
WHERE p.month = '$prev_month' 
  AND d.group='$dist_group'
ORDER BY p.tot_point DESC ;
```

Comment: Unknown column 'p.distributor_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: still '#1054 - Unknown column 'p.distributor_id' in 'on clause'' for the result for your last query :(

Comment: @RobinCastlin I think it is not about his code, It might be that you can't mix `INNER JOIN` with `, (SELECT @rank:=0) AS dummy`. Not sure about that.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal but i need to join it with distributor, because i need it for more spesific group.

Comment: What old version does he use ? That works for all MySQL databases I've ever use

Comment: it's new, version is : 3.5.3

Comment: @Robin Castlin: are you sure? From what I remember - you cannot mix join types.

Comment: so, another ideas to change the join ?

Comment: Changed the `,` to a `CROSS JOIN`. No errors should appear now.

Comment: It appears I've been mistaken. I though I had used that solution in those cases, but a JOIN seems to be the correct solution.